# ¿Cómo llamar a método de fragmento desde Main Activity?

Tags: android, android-fragment

Estoy trabajando con fragmentos, tengo en la actividad principal un BottomNavigationView, al presionar el elemento numero 3 abre un fragmento (navigation_navigator), ahora aclaro que usé este código para que mis fragmentos no se reinicien:

```
    NavigatorFragment navigator = new NavigatorFragment();

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

    replace_fragment(new HomeFragment());
    
}

private void replace_fragment(Fragment fragment) {

    String tag = fragment.getClass().getSimpleName();
    FragmentTransaction tr = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    Fragment curFrag = getSupportFragmentManager().getPrimaryNavigationFragment();
    Fragment cacheFrag = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);

    if (curFrag != null)
        tr.hide(curFrag);

    if (cacheFrag == null) {
        tr.add(R.id.nav_host_fragment, fragment, tag);
    } else {
        tr.show(cacheFrag);
        fragment = cacheFrag;
    }

    tr.setPrimaryNavigationFragment(fragment);
    tr.commit();

}

private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_home:
                replace_fragment(new HomeFragment());
                if (!getSupportActionBar().isShowing()){
                    mostrarBarra();
                }
                return true;

            case R.id.navigation_schedule:
                replace_fragment(new ScheduleFragment());
                if (!getSupportActionBar().isShowing()){
                    mostrarBarra();
                }
                return true;

            case R.id.navigation_calculators:
                replace_fragment(new CalculatorsFragment());
                if (!getSupportActionBar().isShowing()){
                    mostrarBarra();
                }
                return true;

            case R.id.navigation_navigator:
                replace_fragment(new NavigatorFragment());
                if (!getSupportActionBar().isShowing()){
                    navigator.eliminarDatosNavegacion();//*********************Aquí el problema********************************
                }
                ocultarBarra();
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

Cuando vuelvo a presionar el elemento 3 del BottomNavigationView quiero que ejecute un metodo que borra datos de navegación, el metodo está en el fragmento (navigation_navigator), osea que quiero que se ejecute el metodo desde el Main Activity en la línea que dice `navigator.eliminarDatosNavegacion();//*********************Aquí el problema********************************` pero el resultado es
*the result: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.widget.TextView.getText()' on a null object reference*

Aclaro que el metodo funciona bien si se ejecuta desde el mismo fragmento

Este es el código del Fragment

```
public void eliminarDatosNavegacion(){
    if (!textView.getText().toString().equals("Click AQUÍ para elegir")){
        cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
        cookieManager.removeSessionCookie();
        myWebView.clearHistory();
        myWebView.clearFormData();
        myWebView.clearCache(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: El mensaje del LogCat muestra que llamas .getText() en una instancia con valor null, donde realizas ese llamado?

Comment: @Jorgesys una disculpa amigo he estado haciendo pruebas y copié el código incorrecto, ya actualicé el código del Fragment, espero que me puedas ayudar

Comment: Claro, donde obtienes la referencia del textView en tu Fragment me refiero a donde haces uso de findViewById(R.id.???)  ?

Comment: en `onCreateView` del fragment `View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigator, container, false);` `textView = root.findViewById(R.id.tv_sitio_actual);`, como menciono el metodo funciona si se intenta ejecutar desde algún botón del fragment, pero yo quisiera ejecutarlo desde MainActivity

Comment: El método  eliminarDatosNavegacion() entonces se encuentra en el Fragment?

Comment: si amigo se encuentra el el fragment

Comment: Pudieron resolver este problema? Justo estoy teniendo la misma situación:
Quiero utilizar el evento OnKeyDown de un dispositivo, pero solo lo escucha el mainActivity, los fragments ya no. Y si mando llamar un metodo de mi fragment, este no se encuentra instanciado.

Answer (score 0):

Tu pregunta es muy general pero debido al error es que el TextView no está instanciado porque el fragment que lo inicia no está en ejecución, podrías validar tal vez si el TextView es null y así refrescas tus datos sin que de error.

Intenta algo parecido.

```
public void eliminarDatosNavegacion(){
if (textView != null){
   if (!textView.getText().toString().equals("Click AQUÍ para elegir")){
     cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
     cookieManager.removeSessionCookie();
     myWebView.clearHistory();
     myWebView.clearFormData();
     myWebView.clearCache(true);
   }
} else {
     cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
     cookieManager.removeSessionCookie();
     myWebView.clearHistory();
     myWebView.clearFormData();
     myWebView.clearCache(true);
}
```

}

Comment: pasa lo mismo, parece que no me deja manipular ningun elemento ubicado en el fragment, ahora tengo _java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.webkit.CookieManager.removeAllCookie()' on a null object reference
        at com.calificaciones.cumefa.ui.navigator.NavigatorFragment.eliminarDatosNavegacion2(NavigatorFragment.java:188)_ habrá alguna solución? :(

Comment: Otra cosa que puedes utilizar es llamando al método onDetach() que se pueden sobreescribir en las clases que extienden de la clase Fragment y con ello reseteas todos los elementos del Fragment

Comment: No creo que eso ayude porque no quiero que se reseten los elementos, en realidad el metodo onDetach() creo que no se ejecuta cuando presiono los items

Comment: Si tendrías que plantear bien tu pregunta, para poder ayudarte, valida que el fragment esté en ejecución para que puedas validar sus elementos, si no todo lo que intentes hacer siempre te va a marcar en null porque el fragment nunca se inció

Comment: acabo de utilizar Toast en onResume y en onPause para validar si está en ejecución al presionar el item3, el resultado es que en el primer toque se muestra el Toast de onResume, en el segundo toque no se muestra ni onPause ni onResume con lo cual doy por echo que el Fragment sigue en ejecución, onPause ahora solo entra cuando minimizo o cierro la app, creo que el error es que no estoy sabiendo como comunicar de manera correcta el MainActivity con el fragment, seguiré investigando te agradezco mucho tu tiempo